# How to use a function in an external Javascript file in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

This is my first time using an external Javascript file. I am doing the exercise in the murach series of books on Javascript and I am stuck on some pretty basic things. I will show the Javascript coding i did then i will show you the html file. Whenever I click the button to calculate the future value it does nothing even though I have the `onload` event handler.

```
   /*Javascript*/
    var $ = function(id) {
return document.getElementById(id);
};

    function calculateFV(investment, interest, years) {]{

    investment =  $("investment").parseFloat($("investment").value);
    interest =  $("annual_rate").parseFloat($("annual_rate").value);
    years = $("years").parseInt($("years").value);

   var cInterest = investment * interest;

   cInterest = parseFloat(cInterest);
             futureValue = parseFloat(futureValue);
        for (var i = 1; i < years; i++) {
            investment = investment + (cInterest / 100);
             }
           investment = parseFloat(investment).toFixed(2);
                
   $ ("future_value") = investment;
}

window.onload = function() {
$("calculate").onclick = calculateFV;
$("investment").focus();
 };
 /* End of Javascript */

  /* HTML */
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Future Value Calculator</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="future_value.css">
      <script src="future_value.js"></script>
  </head>

    <body>
        <main>
          <h1>Future Value Calculator</h1>
    
          <label for="investment">Total Investment:</label>
          <input type="text" id="investment">
          <span id="investment_error">&nbsp;</span><br>
    
          <label for="rate">Annual Interest Rate:</label>
          <input type="text" id="annual_rate">
          <span id="rate_error">&nbsp;</span><br>
    
          <label for="years">Number of Years:</label>
          <input type="text" id="years">
          <span id="years_error">&nbsp;</span><br>
    
          <label for="future_value">Future Value:</label>
          <input type="text" id="future_value" disabled><br>
    
          <label>&nbsp;</label>
          <input type="button" id="calculate" value="Calculate"><br>      
      </main>
      </body>
      </html>

    /* End of HTML */
```

Comment: in the browser use the developer tools to see the errors (there are typos)

Comment: you have several typos in your code, please have a look at the console in browser

Comment: Yeah it says my parseFloat is not a function. So what do i doto fix the problems. Guys im a beginner i just finished chapter 4 of the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of the typographic errors in your code, there are some other mistakes you do I would like to mention:

1. `parseInt()` is a function; not a method. Therefore it must be used as a function. Like so: `investment = parseFloat($("investment").value);`
   instead of:
   `investment = $("investment").parseFloat($("investment").value);`
2. `$("future_value")` is the textbox; not it's value. To actually have something appear in `$("future_value")`, you have to say: `$("future_value").value = investment`.
3. Your `calculateFV()` function should not have any parameters. `Investment`, `interest` and `years` are local variables inside the function, so your function doesn't require any input.
4. You parse too much and carelessly. In your code you say: `cInterest = parseFloat(cInterest);` and `futureValue = parseFloat(futureValue);`
   • We use `parseFloat()` to parse a string. The above variables contain arithmetic values that occurred after a mathematical operation and not strings. Therefore you do not need to parse them.

I created a jsFiddle with your code corrected and properly functioning. You can find it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/khnrtr1m/).

Good luck in your learning process ☺

Comment: Thank you so much. I didnt know there was a difference between a function and a method

Comment: Be sure to check it out as in more complex projects such errors will be difficult to find out. Check out this Stack Overflow answer to learn more: http://stackoverflow.com/a/155655/6313073

Comment: for some reason when i try to run it in my IDE the javascript isnt running.

Comment: What's your IDE? Eclipse?

Comment: No Komodo X is the IDE

Comment: Have you linked your JS file in your HTML one like: `<script src"..."></script>`?

Comment: Yes i linked it to the javascript. Its saying there is something wrong with the last function in the javascript. check the javascript that the person who answered my question. I copied that to the IDE.